# How to transfer signals through an instance in VHDL

Tags: signals, vhdl, instance

I have top level code that generates values for a signal named cntr.

I am trying to create a simple instance that will read that value cntr and modify that value and send it to LEDs so I can see the behavior. Here is the code for my sub written below.

In the top level code, I have GPIO_LED defined as an OUT(slv) and I have cntr defined as a signal(slv).

On the last line of the code in the sub, you can see the instantiation that I put in the top level.

When I compile, I get the error formal "cntr" does not exist.

How do I get my sub to read the signal generated by the top level?

```
   entity xfer is

        Port (GPIO_LED: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));

    end entity xfer;

    architecture rtl of xfer is

    signal cntr: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

    begin

    GPIO_LED(7 downto 0) <= cntr(27 downto 20) and "11111111";

    end rtl;

    --This goes in top level.
    --xfer_inst: entity work.xfer port map (GPIO_LED => GPIO_LED, cntr=> cntr);
```

Comment: Make your signal a port? i.e. an input or output

Comment: Entities are primary design units which are independently analysed (compiled). They communicate dynamically via ports which are signals.

Comment: I think I have it working properly. My understanding is I make a target variable a port and the direction is germane to the sub file's view that will be instantiated. I move to the other file... I then use port map to tie that port I created to a signal that is in the file with the instance. In the file that makes the "call" there is the same port definition that is in the instantiated file along with the port map that links the two. There is also a signal in that file that allows me to read or write.  Is that correct?